# I need the current selected name to be displayed

Tags: c#, wpf

New to WPF, I have a combo box containing names from a database. When I select a name the details for the previously selected name populates my textboxes. I need the current selected name to be displayed. Can someone tell my why this is happening.

```
    private void comboBoxDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

    {
        string constring = "Data Source=tcp:*****.net;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*******;Password=*****";

        string Query = "select * from Rewards where Name='" + comboBoxDisplay.Text + "' ;";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {

                string sReid = myReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                string sName = myReader.GetString(1);


                txtRewardsId.Text = sReid;
                txtName.Text = sName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) property instead of `Text`.

```
string Query = "select * from Rewards where Name='"
             + comboBoxDisplay.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ;";
```

Comment: Thanks a mill,,,spot on.